# Grails Domain Model passed to on to another closure prior to render

Tags: http, grails

I would like to ask if its possible to have a closure to the rendering form and validation of inputs then let the other controller to the persistence? I am pertaining to this line of code below:

```
def create() {
    if(params.size() <= 2) {
        [modelInstance: new <Domain>()]
    } else {
        def model = new <Domain>(params)
        if(!model.validate()) {
            render(view:"create", model: [modelInstance: model])
            return
        } else {
            chain(action:"save", model: [modelInstance: model])
        }
    }
}

def save() {
//  where the modelInstance object was created from the create closure
    if (!modelInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [modelInstance: modelInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = "Sucess!"
    redirect(action: "show", model: [modelInstance: modelInstance])
}
```

> **Note:** The second closure `save` doesn't have a .gsp file to render, what it
>   only does is do the persistence then redirect the process either pass
>   or fail.

When I use the first modelIstance in the `save` closure, the page return an `HTTP 405` error. This is a result because we couldn't locate the `model` object, yet we used the `chain` method?

Comment: can you provide a stack trace for the 405 error?

Comment: How can I provide? I've tried opening the command prompt via `Open Grails Command Prompt` on my STS since I can't set the environment due security issues.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the actual problem you're trying to solve?  It almost looks like you're trying to use `chain` where a private helper method would be more appropriate.

Comment: @mootinator, sorry for the late response. Can you have your comment as the asnwer. creating a `private Boolean helper` answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use chain where a private helper method would be more appropriate. Try encapsulating the logic you need in both controllers in a separate method.